# Unable to scrape image from Flipkart review section, using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping and trying to scrap image from the Flipkart review section. And I have written some code as below and it is not giving me any kind of output.
And I am also sharing link from which I am trying to scrape.

**Code:**

```
all_div = soup.find_all("div", class_="_1AtVbE col-12-12")
    del all_div[0]
    all_reviews = []
    for review in range(0, len(all_div)):
        rating_elem = all_div[review].find("div", class_="_3LWZlK _1BLPMq")
        review_title_elem = all_div[review].find("p", class_="_2-N8zT")
        if all_div[review].find('div',class_="_21YjFX _2A07HP") is not None:
            review_image = all_div[review].find('div',class_="_21YjFX _2A07HP").text
            review
```

**Flipkart Image:**

[image: Flipkar review section]

**link:**

[link from where I am trying to scrap:](https://www.flipkart.com/prowl-tiger-shroff-push-up-board-upper-body-workout-push-up-bar/product-reviews/itm0487671f4df34?pid=BAAGM82GUHTQ3KFZ&lid=LSTBAAGM82GUHTQ3KFZVCWDQ9&marketplace=FLIPKART&page=1)